# video calling app for android to desktop

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc

Which is the **best api** to use to build the **video calling app**

I have seen about `web RTC` which can't track the record of the two or more clients, it just connect them, because it is **client to client** protocol, the **signalling server** only involves to make the hand shake of the two or more clients.

**Can you suggest me the protocol which keeps the record of video calling, is there any protocol exist?**

Comment: `best api` there is nothing best. Everything is best only for somebody's opinion, which is **opinion-based**, which is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: What do you mean by "record of video calling"? Do you want to record the video call?

If so, then you'd want a SFU. If the clients connect to the SFU instead of each other, then you can get the SFU to do the recording for you.

Comment: @JoshMackey no, i dont want recording, i mean to say that i want the record of video calling, like who called who, when(time), call duration, when call ended, and many other attributes

Comment: You can get Who and When via your signalling. For the rest, you'll need an SFU. An SFU is a piece of software that the peers connect to instead of each other, and then it forwards the media data onwards to other peers. This would let you get all the other attributes you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout  http://www.pjsip.org/

PJSIP has the ability to do both audio and video signaling over SIP and  works great on embedded devices as well as desktop environments.

IMHO WebRTC isn't mature enough for large scale deployments.  Maybe in another 12-18 months, but today it's still too fragile. If you want consistent day after day performance and stability I suggest speaking the same language as the telcos: SIP and G711.

Comment: I disagree that WebRTC isn't mature enough. Chrome and Firefox support it completely, with Safari offers support in its newest version. At it's base, WebRTC works via the same method that SIP and VoIP does, it just is signalling agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

You can get Who and When via your signalling. For the rest, you'll need an SFU. An SFU is a piece of software that the peers connect to instead of each other, and then it forwards the media data onwards to other peers. This would let you get all the other attributes you want.

I work for an WebRTC company and we have a SFU product called LiveSwitch (https://www.frozenmountain.com/products-services/liveswitch/). Check it out if you want to go the paid route.